# Save Directory Specific history for zshell

Tags: linux, command, line, history

I am trying to save my directory specific command line history. AKA, when I am in a directory called Happy, and I arrow up, I don't want to see all of my past command line history, I only want to see the history that was done in the specific Happy directory.

I also want all of this to get saved to a file so that I can access it later. Perhaps save it to files organized by directory, or by date, I don't know what would be best. Does anyone have anything like this set up?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you could use this script on GitHub. Excerpt from README:

> ## [Per-Directory-History](http://github.com/jimhester/per-directory-history)
>
> Per directory history for zsh, as well as global history, and the
>   ability to toggle between them with ^G.
>
> This is a implementation of per directory history for zsh, some 
>   implementations of which exist in bash.  It also implements
>   a per-directory-history-toggle-history function to change from using
>   the  directory history to using the global history.  In both cases the
>   history is  always saved to both the global history and the directory
>   history, so the  toggle state will not effect the saved histories. 
>   Being able to switch  between global and directory histories on the
>   fly is a novel feature as far  as I am aware.
>
> This is a standalone repository for the script, however it is also
>   included in [oh-my-zsh](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh) as a plugin.